# Cross-compile wxGtk

Tags: c++, cross-compiling, wxwidgets

I have to cross-compile wxGtk (an old version: 2.8.11) and managed to setup the environment so that `configure` runs successfully.

```
$ export CC=/opt/my_toolchain/toolchain_base/bin/i686-pc-linux-gnu-gcc
$ export CXX=/opt/my_toolchain/toolchain_base/bin/i686-pc-linux-gnu-g++
$ export CPPFLAGS=-I/opt/my_toolchain/additional_libs/usr/include/
$ export PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR=/opt/my_toolchain/additional_libs/
$ export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/my_toolchain/additional_libs/usr/lib/pkgconfig
$ export PKG_CONFIG_DIR=/opt/my_toolchain/additional_libs/usr/lib/pkgconfig
$ export PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR=/opt/my_toolchain/additional_libs/sysroot/usr/lib/
// LDFLAGS evtl falsch?? nicht ueberschreiben!?
$ export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/my_toolchain/additional_libs/lib/ -L/opt/my_toolchain/additional_libs/usr/lib/"
$ export CFLAGS="-Wl,-rpath-link=/opt/my_toolchain/additional_libs/lib/ -Wl,-rpath-link=/opt/my_toolchain/additional_libs/usr/lib/"
$ export CXXFLAGS="-Wl,-rpath-link=/opt/my_toolchain/additional_libs/lib/ -Wl,-rpath-link=/opt/my_toolchain/additional_libs/usr/lib/"
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/my_toolchain/additional_libs/lib/:/opt/my_toolchain/additional_libs/usr/lib/:/opt/my_toolchain/additional_libs/usr/lib/:/opt/my_toolchain/additional_libs/lib/
$ pkg-config --define-variable=pc_path=/opt/my_toolchain/additional_libs/usr/lib/pkgconfig pkg-config

wxGTK-2.8.11 $ ./configure --enable-unicode --disable-shared --prefix=/usr/local/<targetname>
[...]
Configured wxWidgets 2.8.11 for `x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'

Which GUI toolkit should wxWidgets use?                 GTK+ 2
Should wxWidgets be compiled into single library?       no
Should wxWidgets be compiled in debug mode?             no
Should wxWidgets be linked as a shared library?         no
Should wxWidgets be compiled in Unicode mode?           yes
What level of wxWidgets compatibility should be enabled?
                                   wxWidgets 2.4      no
                                   wxWidgets 2.6      yes
Which libraries should wxWidgets use?
                                   jpeg               sys
                                   png                sys
                                   regex              builtin
                                   tiff               sys
                                   zlib               sys
                                   odbc               no
                                   expat              sys
                                   libmspack          no
                                   sdl                no
```

However the subsequent `make` reports an error:

```
wxGTK-2.8.11 $ make
[...]
bk-make-pch ./.pch/wxprec_netlib/wx/wxprec.h.gch wx/wxprec.h /opt/my_toolchain/toolchain_base/bin/i686-pc-linux-gnu-g++ -I./.pch/wxprec_netlib -D__WXGTK__     -DWXBUILDING      -I./src/regex  -DwxUSE_GUI=0 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGE_FILES -I/mnt/cifs/osb_m/10_Competence_Centers/21_CC_IE/22_Kunden_Technik_Aktiv/Holmer/Software/Holmer_VT-Server/wxGTK-2.8.11/lib/wx/include/gtk2-unicode-release-static-2.8 -I./include -pthread -I/opt/my_toolchain/additional_libs//usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/opt/my_toolchain/additional_libs//usr/lib/gtk-2.0/include -I/opt/my_toolchain/additional_libs//usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/opt/my_toolchain/additional_libs//usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/opt/my_toolchain/additional_libs//usr/include/cairo -I/opt/my_toolchain/additional_libs//usr/include/pixman-1 -I/opt/my_toolchain/additional_libs//usr/include/libpng16 -I/opt/my_toolchain/additional_libs//usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/opt/my_toolchain/additional_libs//usr/include/libpng16 -I/opt/my_toolchain/additional_libs//usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/opt/my_toolchain/additional_libs//usr/include/harfbuzz -I/opt/my_toolchain/additional_libs//usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/opt/my_toolchain/additional_libs//usr/include/freetype2 -I/opt/my_toolchain/additional_libs//usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/opt/my_toolchain/additional_libs//usr/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/opt/my_toolchain/additional_libs/usr/include/ -DWX_PRECOMP -pthread -Wall -Wundef -Wno-ctor-dtor-privacy -O2 -fno-strict-aliasing -Wl,-rpath-link=/opt/my_toolchain/additional_libs/lib/ -Wl,-rpath-link=/opt/my_toolchain/additional_libs/usr/lib/
In file included from /opt/my_toolchain/additional_libs/usr/include/math.h:46:0,
             from ./include/wx/math.h:19,
             from ./include/wx/wx.h:30,
             from ./include/wx/wxprec.h:68:
/opt/my_toolchain/additional_libs/usr/include/bits/mathdef.h:47:6: warning: "__FP_FAST_FMA" is not defined [-Wundef]
/opt/my_toolchain/additional_libs/usr/include/bits/mathdef.h:51:6: warning: "__FP_FAST_FMAF" is not defined [-Wundef]
/opt/my_toolchain/additional_libs/usr/include/bits/mathdef.h:55:6: warning: "__FP_FAST_FMAL" is not defined [-Wundef]
/opt/my_toolchain/toolchain_base/bin/../i686-pc-linux-gnu/libc/usr/lib/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:12022: recipe for target '.pch/wxprec_netlib/wx/wxprec.h.gch' failed
make: *** [.pch/wxprec_netlib/wx/wxprec.h.gch] Error 1
```

I've printed the compiler command which reports the issue:

```
/opt/my_toolchain/toolchain_base/bin/i686-pc-linux-gnu-g++ \
-I./.pch/wxprec_baselib -D__WXGTK__ -DWXBUILDING \
-I./src/regex \
-DwxUSE_GUI=0 -DwxUSE_BASE=1 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGE_FILES \
-I/path/to/wxGTK-2.8.11/lib/wx/include/gtk2-unicode-release-static-2.8 \
-I./include \
-pthread \
-I/opt/my_toolchain/additional_libs//usr/include/gtk-2.0 \
-I/opt/my_toolchain/additional_libs//usr/lib/gtk-2.0/include \
-I/opt/my_toolchain/additional_libs//usr/include/pango-1.0 \
-I/opt/my_toolchain/additional_libs//usr/include/atk-1.0 \
-I/opt/my_toolchain/additional_libs//usr/include/cairo \
-I/opt/my_toolchain/additional_libs//usr/include/pixman-1 \
-I/opt/my_toolchain/additional_libs//usr/include/libpng16 \
-I/opt/my_toolchain/additional_libs//usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 \
-I/opt/my_toolchain/additional_libs//usr/include/libpng16 \
-I/opt/my_toolchain/additional_libs//usr/include/pango-1.0 \
-I/opt/my_toolchain/additional_libs//usr/include/harfbuzz \
-I/opt/my_toolchain/additional_libs//usr/include/pango-1.0 \
-I/opt/my_toolchain/additional_libs//usr/include/freetype2 \
-I/opt/my_toolchain/additional_libs//usr/include/glib-2.0 \
-I/opt/my_toolchain/additional_libs//usr/lib/glib-2.0/include \
-I/opt/my_toolchain/additional_libs/usr/include/ \
-DWX_PRECOMP -pthread -Wall -Wundef -Wno-ctor-dtor-privacy -O2 -fno-strict-aliasing \
-Wl,-rpath-link=/opt/my_toolchain/additional_libs/lib/ \
-Wl,-rpath-link=/opt/my_toolchain/additional_libs/usr/lib/ \
-o ./.pch/wxprec_baselib/wx/wxprec.h.gch \
-MMD -MF \
./.deps/___pch_wxprec_baselib_wx_wxprec_h_gch.d \
./include/wx/wxprec.h
```

If I remove the two the `-Wl,-rpath-link=` statements from this compiler command and invoke it manually, the command succeeds.

It seems the additional `-Wl` statements make the compiler miss the source file with the `main()`-function (which seems to be provided via `./include/wx/wxprec.h`), but I don't really see how that could happen.

I'd be grateful about any advice how I can address this problem.

*Update*

The `configure`-Script has the usual options (no `--source`)

```
--build=BUILD     configure for building on BUILD [guessed]
--host=HOST       cross-compile to build programs to run on HOST [BUILD]
--target=TARGET   configure for building compilers for TARGET [HOST]
```

where `--target` is of no interest. The other options I'll have to check. As I mentioned in the comments, I've so far only seen them being used with prefixes e.g. `aarch64-linux-gnu` for toolchains from package repositories which are in the `$PATH`, and with according libraries etc.

So I've added the folder for toolchain binaries to path and configured with

```
./configure --enable-unicode --disable-shared --prefix=/usr/local/<target> --host=i686-pc-linux-gnu


configure: WARNING: If you wanted to set the --build type, don't use --host.
If a cross compiler is detected then cross compile mode will be used.
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking target system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
```

That looks correct. I want to build on my local machine for another target.

But:

```
checking for GTK+ - version >= 2.0.0... no
*** Could not run GTK+ test program, checking why...
*** The test program failed to compile or link. See the file config.log for the
*** exact error that occured. This usually means GTK+ is incorrectly installed.
configure: error:
The development files for GTK+ were not found. For GTK+ 2, please
ensure that pkg-config is in the path and that gtk+-2.0.pc is
installed. For GTK+ 1.2 please check that gtk-config is in the path,
and that the version is 1.2.3 or above. Also check that the
libraries returned by 'pkg-config gtk+-2.0 --libs' or 'gtk-config
--libs' are in the LD_LIBRARY_PATH or equivalent.
```

Unfortunately that makes sense. The toolchain itself only has some libraries, but does not have the GTK-libraries.

```
/opt/my_toolchain/toolchain_base/
```

The GTK libraries and other libraries are in a separate folder:

```
/opt/my_toolchain/additional_libs/
```

And the toolchain's binaries don't know about this folder.

I think the whole issue arises because wxGtk builds libraries for the `host` = `i686-pc-linux-gnu`, but also builds executables (e.g. `wx-config`) for the `build-system` = `x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu`.

Comment: 1. Why do you try an outdated version of the library? 2. Your configure line missing 2 important option `source` and `target` - they both needed for cross-compilation. 3. You set those options yourself as part of one of the environment variables.  Just remove it.

Comment: 1. It's an old SW and I try to do minimal invasive changes. 2./3. I can check in a few days, but imho `configure --help` didn't show the options `--host`, `--build` and `--target`. `--source` I don't know at all. Also, afaik, those options refer to some kind of prefix/suffix of toolchain binaries in the `$PATH` installed via package manager. which is not the case here.

Comment: those options are for selecting an appropriate toolchain and making sure the appropriate code will be generated. If you cross-compiling, you should supply them. Unfortunately, I'm not well versed in them so you might ask a more generic C++ question or ask on wx forum.

Comment: the software might be old, but if you find a problem, you will need to build it with the latest version. 2.i is not maintained anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wxGtk 2.8.11 cross-build is finally working with the following setup:

```
export PATH=/opt/my_toolchain/toolchain_base/bin/:${PATH}
export PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR=/opt/my_toolchain/additional_libs
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/my_toolchain/additional_libs/usr/lib/pkgconfig
export PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_SYSTEM_CFLAGS=1
# make sure those env vars are not left from previous setup
unset  CC
unset  CXX
unset  CPPFLAGS
unset  CFLAGS
unset  CXXFLAGS
unset  LD_LIBRARY_PATH
unset  LDFLAGS
unset  PKG_CONFIG_DIR
unset  PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR

./configure --enable-unicode --disable-shared --prefix=/usr/local/<target> --host=i686-pc-linux-gnu --build=x86_64-linux-gnu
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: I hoe you will update wxWidgets to the newer version. There are many fixes and new features that you might need to use.

Comment: In general I agree. But there are two obstacles: (1) the effort to upgrade to a recent wxGtk version (I've not done the original wx integration and don't know wx at all). (2) the target systems run on Ubuntu 9.04. We cannot upgrade those systems with reasonable effort, and newer wxGtk versions would for sure need libraries which are not available on those systems.

Comment: To answer - 1) upgrading from 2.8 to 3.0 should be very painless. Just install wxGTK-3.0.<latest> and recompile your software. Watch out for the string conversion, because ANSI build is retired. No other major issues should arise. 2) wx dev team goes to extreme effort to keep compatibility with the older OS. You can still compile everythinmg with GTK+2 and WinXP SP2 was retired about 2 years ago. I would try to do the upgrade to at least 3.0.<latest>. If you have any issues you can always go to wx forum or wx-users ML.

Comment: you can also contact me directly for the help. Will be happy to do that as I perform just this task not so long ago.

Comment: thanks for the info, I appreciate your effort to convince me! I'll see, if wx is easygoing with backwards compatibility then that may be okay. However we'll need to check that it runs stable on all targets, and need the approval from the customer (who will have to pay for the effort).

Comment: I understand. Just tell them that 2.8 series is unsupported and it is better to stay current.